# Fancy box post back problem

Tags: fancybox

I,m using fancy box for opening a new aspx page . Before any post back in that page this works perfectly . But if any post backs happens in this page then this page will open in the normal window and not in fancy box.

Comment: can u paste code. I want to see which option r u using.

Answer (score 1):

I think u r using normal option like : Inline - modal window

use iframe option. it will not open in normal window after postback

```
$("#MyID").fancybox({
        'width'             : '75%',
        'height'            : '75%',
        'autoScale'         : false,
        'transitionIn'      : 'none',
        'transitionOut'     : 'none',
        'type'              : 'iframe'
    });
```